# How to create a TabLayout with SlidingTabStrip placed at top of view and not at bottom

Tags: java, android, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

Using Android support design library I would like to change TabLayout.SlidingTabStrip position from bottom to top. The problem is that SlidingTabStrip is private class so I find no good solution to extend it and override its draw method.

This is default:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

So to simplify I would like to change 2nd line this method:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    if(this.mIndicatorLeft >= 0 && this.mIndicatorRight > this.mIndicatorLeft) {
        canvas.drawRect((float)this.mIndicatorLeft, (float)(this.getHeight() - this.mSelectedIndicatorHeight), (float)this.mIndicatorRight, (float)this.getHeight(), this.mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }
}
```

from this:

```
canvas.drawRect((float)this.mIndicatorLeft, (float)(this.getHeight() - this.mSelectedIndicatorHeight), (float)this.mIndicatorRight, (float)this.getHeight(), this.mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
```

into this method:

```
canvas.drawRect((float)this.mIndicatorLeft, 0f, (float)this.mIndicatorRight, (float)this.selectedIndicatorHeight, this.mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
```

How can I accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: At the moment I can't see a way that this is possible. You might just have to set a transparent color on the indicator, and then put a custom indicator on top of the TabLayout :/

Comment: currently best implementation I have come up with is simply to copy implementation from support library and rewrite draw method of SlidingTapStrip so it suits my needs. It works, but it is a bad approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout and override its onDraw(Canvas canvas)

Comment: This won't work as it's in the inner private class SlidingTabStrip in TabLayout that the actual draw(..) implementation resides.